# How to show Json data over JQuery with ajax in a bootstrap panel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get the information from a json file which is structured like this:

```
{
 "title": "title",
 "subtitle": "Select2",
 "category": "C#",
 "desc": "this is a description",
 "text":"this is some text",
 "keywords": [
   "select",
   "autocomplete",
   "typeahead",
   "dropdown",
   "multiselect",
   "tag",
   "tagging"
  ],
 "images": [
   "path1",
   "path2",
   "path3"
  ],
  "author": {
   "name": "zh",
   "url": "someURL"
  } 
}
```

Getting the Json file is no problem but rendering the panel with the data of json file doesn't work. 
What is wrong?

My code which doesn't work : https://jsfiddle.net/x7e9650s/1/

See my Online here : rocketunit.ch/codesnippet.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: What response do you get from server?

Comment: @Justinas post edited to see example online.

Comment: console your json first, if it will work, then iterate it using $.each as my suggestion.